# query performance individually is fine, but when run together it doesn't finish

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am at a loss as to how to optimize this query. I am using it to insert the the selected columns into another table. However, This query in its entirety just hangs and seems like it won't finish. I am unable to run the `EXPLAIN` with `ANALYZE` because of the hanging. And my sql knowledge is at its limit, I have a very hard time reading the query plans. Each of the subqueries, when run individually run fine. I can even run a combination of the three, ie: the first subquery with the joins or the first joins with the final. But when all three are run together, it hangs and seems to not ever finish. I've let it run for 5minutes with no luck. The first subquery has 53527 records, the dim_products table has 109. I have changed the order of the joins if that might help and it didn't. Any help is appreciated.

```
   explain (costs,verbose)SELECT a.addon_id,t.transaction_id
         from (
               SELECT product_id, addon_id
                 FROM scv.fact_addons
             ) a
       join scv.dim_products p using (product_id)
       join (
            SELECT t.transaction_id, e.identifier
                from (
                    select p.productsku as identifier, d.ticket_id from etl.products p
                    join scv.dim_tickets d on d.ticket_number = p.ticketno
                    where etl_batch_file_id = 509
                ) e
                join (
                    select transaction_id, ticket_id
                     from scv.fact_ticket_transactions t
                ) t using (ticket_id)
        ) t using (identifier);
```

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=1.72..66.06 rows=6 width=8)"
"  Output: fact_addons.addon_id, t.transaction_id"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.43..2.44 rows=1 width=8)"
"        Output: p.product_id, t.transaction_id"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.01..1.79 rows=1 width=8)"
"              Output: p.product_id, d.ticket_id"
"              Inner Unique: true"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..1.10 rows=1 width=13)"
"                    Output: p.product_id, p_1.ticketno"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    ->  Index Scan using "index_etl.products_on_etl_batch_file_id" on etl.products p_1  (cost=0.44..0.70 rows=1 width=17)"
"                          Output: p_1.id, p_1.sale_id, p_1.ticketno, p_1.transaction_date, p_1.item_quantity, p_1.item_single_value, p_1.productsku, p_1.family_name, p_1.type_description, p_1.product_description, p_1.product_serial, p_1.from_date, p_1.to_date, p_1.etl_batch_file_id, p_1.imported, p_1.created_at, p_1.updated_at, p_1.customer_id"
"                          Index Cond: (p_1.etl_batch_file_id = 509)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using dim_products_identifier on scv.dim_products p  (cost=0.14..0.40 rows=1 width=12)"
"                          Output: p.product_id, p.identifier, p.description, p.type_description, p.brand_id, p.family_name, p.valid_from_date, p.valid_to_date, p.valid_from_date_id, p.valid_to_date_id, p.created_date, p.updated_date"
"                          Index Cond: ((p.identifier)::text = (p_1.productsku)::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using idx_unique_tickets on scv.dim_tickets d  (cost=0.43..0.69 rows=1 width=13)"
"                    Output: d.ticket_id, d.sale_id, d.ticket_number, d.sale_date, d.sale_date_id"
"                    Index Cond: ((d.ticket_number)::text = (p_1.ticketno)::text)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_ticket_xaction_ticket_id_transaction_id on scv.fact_ticket_transactions t  (cost=0.42..0.55 rows=2 width=8)"
"              Output: t.ticket_id, t.transaction_id"
"              Index Cond: (t.ticket_id = d.ticket_id)"
"  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_fact_addons_product_addon_id on scv.fact_addons  (cost=0.29..34.21 rows=588 width=8)"
"        Output: fact_addons.product_id, fact_addons.addon_id"
"        Index Cond: (fact_addons.product_id = p.product_id)"
```

Comment: Please `analyze etl.products` - it's possible that the statistics of this table are not current. Also try to avoid those subselects: `from (SELECT product_id, addon_id FROM scv.fact_addons) a` and `(select transaction_id, ticket_id from scv.fact_ticket_transactions t) t`. Just use `from scv.fact_addons as a` and `join scv.fact_ticket_transactions t`. Your subselects can make the database unable to use indexes properly.

Comment: Ah ok. I will get on that and let you know how it went :D. Thank you!

Comment: I've done what you've suggested and it worked pretty well. It's definitely a lot faster now, although still pretty slow. I think there is some other underlying issue that I'm unaware of. Might be my machine or pgadmin slowing things down. If you want to put your comment as an answer, I can accept it :D